# DNS configuration for numerous departments

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, domain

I have two departments in my network. In each department I have DC with running website. 
I need to configure DNS to work at this way:

- If I go to website1.somedomain.com from department1 it sends me to DC1.
- If I go to website1.somedomain.com from department2 it sends me to DC2.
- If I go to website2.somedomain.com from department1 or department2 it sends me to DC1.

How can I configure it?

DCs are Win 2008 both are at the same domain (lets say mydomain.org).

edit:
My problem is with replication.

- All the workstations at department1 configured to use DNS at DC1.
- All the workstations at department2 configured to use DNS at DC2.
- At the planning stage, I thought to create two zones at DC1

  - one replicated somedomain.com, which points website2.somedomain.com to DC1
  - non replicated zone somedomain.com at DC1, which points website1.somedomain.com to DC1.
  - non replicated zone somedomain.com at DC2, which points website1.somedomain.com to DC2.

But I'm not so much familiar with Windows DNS, so,

1. How I can create number of zones with the same name?
2. How to make a non replicated zones?

The possible solution is to create non replicated zones at DC1 and DC2, but I don't know how can I do this too. So I need help.

edit: OK. I did it this way: At all the DC's I created somedomain.com zone and unchecked "Store the zone in Active Directory" (this disable replication) and manually created all the rules. Not the most beautiful solution, but it works. Thanks to all.

Comment: The web sites run on the DC's? Are these departments on the same layer 3 subnet?

Comment: Yes, the web sites run on the DC's. And departments are not at the same subnet. Thet separated with WAN.

Comment: OK. Your answer to my question tells me everything I need to know. You should be able to do this with netmask ordering (enabled by default) on the DNS servers, assuming you can configure DNS and the web sites correctly - http://blogs.technet.com/b/askpfeplat/archive/2013/02/18/how-netmask-ordering-feature-in-dns-affects-the-resultant-queries.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my case its problematic to configure the NetMask, because I have DNS already configured for mydomain.org. What I can do is only to add and configure new zones, such way that mydomain.org zone wouldn't be affected. So I need another solution...

Comment: You're not understanding netmask ordering. You don't have to "configure your netmask". If each department is on a different subnet, and you create an A record for website1 with the ip address of each DC on each subnet then when clients on each subnet resolve the website1 name they'll resolve it to the DC in their subnet. For website2 you'll only create one A record that points to DC1. So you don't have to change your DNS or create additional zones or anything else. Create two A records for website1, one that is set to the DC1 ip address and the other that is set to the DC2 ip address.

Comment: I've understood it. But by default it works with C Class addresses, and it doesn't help me. It the same problem as described in the article. I need to change LocalNetPriorityNetMask to 0x0000FFFF or eaven to 0x00FFFFFF.

Answer (score 1):

In a unix and bind world you use views.

In a windows world, you create two separate dns servers.
DNS Server 1 points website1.com to dc1
DNS server 2 points website1.com to dc2
Both DNS servers point website2.com to dc1

Workstations in department1 are configured to use DNS server 1
Workstations in department2 are configured to use DNS server 2

...Depending on your implementation, you may or may not want active directory managing these zones...

Comment: Hey. I've edited my question. My problem is a replication.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you running a website on a domain controller?  Microsoft does NOT recommend doing this for security and functionality reasons.  I would recommend you spin up a second server for each department.

Both websites have the same URL?

Comment: This is not critical for me, where I run the website. If I have separate server at each department for running websites, I have the same problem with DNS. And yes, they have the same URL website1.somedomain.com.

Comment: I echo your sentiment that web hosting should not be done on the domain controller. However, this response would be more appropriate as a comment than as an answer, since it doesn't explain why it fails.